# There are 190 people on the beach. 110 are wearing sunglasses, 70 are wearing bathing suits, and 95 are wearing a hat.

Tags: combinatorics, inclusion-exclusion

There are 190 people on the beach. 110 are wearing sunglasses, 70 are wearing bathing suits, and 95 are wearing a hat. Everyone is wearing at least one of these items. 30 are wearing both bathing suits and sunglasses. 25 are wearing both bathing suits and a hat. 40 are wearing both sunglasses and a hat. How many people are wearing all three items?

Apparently the answer is 25 but I cannot get to it. I tried using Venn diagrams and still couldn't get to it.

Comment: Look up the [principle of inclusion and exclusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle)

Comment: The answer isn't $25$.  What did you get?

Comment: I could not figure it out.

Comment: Indeed, the actual answer is not $25$.

Comment: Could you help me then?

Comment: It is great that you guys know that the answer is not 25, but how about helping me with it then? Isn't that the point of this...?

Comment: You have been told that the answer is not 25, so how do you know the answer you got is wrong ? Show us your effort. A link which directly gives the correct formula has also been provided. What more do you need ?

Answer (score 2):

The answer is not $25$...

By PIE, we have that $190=110+70+95-(30+25+40)+x$

Simplifying, we get that $x=10$.

Hence, $10$ people are wearing all three.

Answer (score 1):

Let $x$ be number of people wearing all three items. Since 30 people are wearing bathing suits and sunglasses, we know that $30 - x$ are wearing just bathing suits and sunglasses. Similarly, $25 - x$ are wearing just bathing suits and hats, while $40 - x$ are wearing just sunglasses and a hat.

To find the number of people wearing just sunglasses, we subtract the people who are wearing sunglasses with other items from the total number of people wearing sunglasses, which is $110 - (30 - x) - (40 - x) - x = 40 + x$. Similarly, the number of people wearing just hats is $30 + x$, while the number of people wearing just bathing suits is $15 + x$.

Since the total number of people on the beach is 190, and everyone is wearing at least one of the items, we have:\begin{align*}
190 &= (15 + x) + (40 + x) + (30 + x) \\
&\qquad+ (25 - x ) + (30 - x) + (40 - x) + x\\
&= 180 + x.
\end{align*}We can then solve for $x$, so the number of people on the beach wearing all three items is $x = \boxed{10}$.